# In IIS, how do you configure folder access for basic authentication?

Tags: iis

In IIS 7, how do you configure folder access for basic authentication against domain?

I've done the following:

1. Enabled Authentication - Basic Mode.
2. This seems to work for regular folders, but once I convert the folder to an Application in IIS, users get rejected unless I add them specifically to the Security item in Windows.  Do I need to do this for every single user?

What if I need all members of domain to access a  given url?

Comment: "I add them specifically to the Security item in Windows." What's your default settings there before adding users one by one? Groups such as `Users` should be there. Check "\inetpub\wwwroot" section in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/981949/description-of-default-permissions-and-user-rights-for-iis-7-0-and-lat

Comment: there is iis_users and system.

Comment: Then you have to add `Users` as the KB article indicates, instead of individual user accounts.

Comment: How is that related to the application pool though?

Comment: I didn't say anything about "application pool".

Comment: Oh your right. The app pool doesn't effect anything. I had the rights of the user in    when i was testing.

Comment: I think you are right, it's look like the domain group is not listed under security. When i converted it to an application, does that blow away the inherited permissions?